# Python packages automatically bundled by PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a written Python code while using following modules:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageGrab
from tkinter.colorchooser import *
from tkinter import filedialog
```

Are these modules automatically packed into the `.exe` file when I bundle the application with Pyinstaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are these modules automatically packed into the `.exe` file when I bundle the application with Pyinstaller?

Yes, they are. As long as they are one of the [packages supported by PyInstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages) or part of the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) — with some exceptions.

In fact, the PyInstaller documentation (linked above) has this to say:

> Most packages will work out of the box with PyInstaller.
>
> This is especially true for pure Python packages and for packages not requiring additional files.
>
> As for the packages in the Python standard library we only list the exceptions that don't work correctly; thus, if not listed, it works correctly.

Tkinter, which is part of the standard library, is *not* listed, while the Pillow library (`PIL` package) *is*. So this should work out of the box.

Ultimately, you have to try it out and see. Inspired by the code above, here is a self-contained example that takes a screen-shot, opens a "Save as" dialog provided by Tkinter to have the user specify a file name, then saves the screen-shot as a PNG image using Pillow:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from tkinter import filedialog

screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
screenshot.save(filename)
```

It can be bundled as an `.exe` (Windows) application with the following command on the (Windows) command prompt, provided `pyinstaller` has been installed:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile example.py
```

(Tested with Python 3.7.4 (including Tkinter) on Windows 10, Pillow 6.1.0, pyInstaller 3.5.)

Answer (score 1):

You might be searching for [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1):

Like @E.B's answer, cx_freeze is a choice, however if its too complex for you, you could try [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), which is a simpler command-line based tool.

Comment: Well, I have written that I'm trying to do it that way, but I'm getting unworking exe

Comment: Have move the exe out of the folder you exported in? If thats the case then it wont run, you have to keep it with its generate files, but if you want it to be cleaner you can use the --onefile  --clean arguments.

Comment: No, I left it there, it opened (in console) for a fraction of second but, then closed

Comment: Ah, have you tried double clicking on the .exe instead, and what do you mean by "console", are you using linux?

Comment: Well, I mean command line, its also usually recalled as console

Comment: How can I tell pyinstaller which packages/modules i want to include?

Comment: I beleive it does it for you? Tkinter is a builtin, pillow is an outside module, maybe its not creating the dependencies? Let me quickly try something.

Comment: Figured it out, pyinstaller does not count outside dependencies like modules installed with pip. Take a look at the pyinstaller docs and check if theres an area for specifying modules.

Comment: I saw what is cmd saying when opening exe: something about missing dll...

Comment: Missing dll, that means it definiely just a dependency issue, try using cx_freeze.